# SQL Outer joins

Tags: mysql, sql

Three tables **courses,registration,students**

columns in students

`firstname,lastname,studentid,major,admitdate,graddate,gender,dob`

columns in registration

`courseid,studentid`

columns in courses

`coursenumber,coursename,credits`

select statement I need to modify

```
select lastname as 'Last Name',sum(credits) as 'Credits Registered For' from students   as s
inner join registration as r on s.studentid = r.studentid
inner join courses as c on c.coursenumber = c.courseid
group by last name;
```

the question on the lab is... Modify the previous query to show all students, even if they have not registered for a class. You should have 14 rows. Students who are not registered will show NULL in output.

I know this requires outer join of some sort but I'm not fully grasping these joins i've read multiple posts on here and other sites but can't seem figure it out.

Comment: This may help you learn about joins: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: change `inner` to `LEFT`

Answer (score 3):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
select  lastname as 'Last Name',
        sum(credits) as 'Credits Registered For' 
from    students   as s
        LEFT join registration as r on s.studentid = r.studentid
        LEFT join courses as c on c.coursenumber = r.courseid
group by last name;
```

Comment: wow I could have sworn I did that exact query right there and it wouldn't work i've been doing homework much too long! Thank you!

Comment: so you see now the difference between `INNER` and `LEFT` (*which is an outer join*), anyway you're welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT  s.lastname AS 'Last Name',
        sum(c.credits) AS 'Credits Registered For' 
FROM    students    s
        LEFT JOIN registration  r ON (s.studentid = r.studentid)
        INNER JOIN courses  c ON (c.coursenumber = r.courseid)
GROUP BY lastname;
```

**note:** no need to use `AS` while giving alias to table name

Comment: Despite the `AS` not being required for the alias, it can (and does in my opinion) help with readability.

Comment: but it will lead confusion bcoz we are using table alias as well as column alias together in one query so keeping both alias different we must not use alias for table name although column alias is mandatory